# Bash [: missing `]' on if statements

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So, I have this code here for linux bash which i hope to use for a simple Caesar cipher, and after many hours of trial and error, I decided to try and find a solution on here, **even though this question has been asked many times** I cannot seem to find what I am doing wrong. Here is the code.

```
    #!/bin/bash
read -p 1
if [ "$1" == "E" ]
then 
read word
echo $word | tr '[A-Z]' '[X-ZA-W]'
elif [ "$1" == "D" ]
then 
read word
echo $word | tr '[X-ZA-W]' '[A-Z]'
else
echo "Unsupported command"
fi
```

errors here

security.txt: line 3: [: missing `]'
security.txt: line 7: [: missing`]'

Comment: that was a mistake i did in pasting it

Comment: Your file has DOS line endings, so the final `]` on a line is really a `]\r`; `bash` only recognizes the `\n` part of the `\r\n` as terminating the line.